# Expand modulus squared

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Is it possible to make a function in Mathematica that expands expressions of the form

$$|z + w|^2 = |z|^2 + 2\text{Re} \overline{z}w + |w|^2?$$

Preferably it should also be able to handle things like
$$\left |\sum_{i = 1}^n z_i \right |^2.$$
The last thing can obviously be mathematically deduced from the first one by consecutively applying the first equality.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[]` with a proper setting of `TargetFunctions` is supposed to be able to do this, but I can't figure out how to have *Mathematica* produce the form you want...

Comment: `ComplexExpand` won't do it alone, in this case. Also, the OPs formula is incorrect the RHS should be $$\newcommand{asq}[1]{|#1|^2} \asq{z} + 2\,\Re(\bar{z} w) + \asq{w} .$$

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry, typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: @J.M. `ComplexExpand` assumes that all variables are real, which is not the case here.  `FunctionExpand` gets you closer, but not quite there.

Comment: @Szabolcs the second argument of `ComplexExpand` lets you tell it that some vars are complex

Comment: ComplexExpand[Expand[ComplexExpand[ee, {z,w}, TargetFunctions->{Conjugate}]], {z,w},
  TargetFunctions->{Abs}] might come within shouting distance

Comment: Yes, it seems to be frequently forgotten that one can always specify which variables are complex in `ComplexExpand[]`... ;)

Comment: Wow, TargetFunctions is awesome! That will save me oodles of time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like (ComplexExpand with all three arguments, Expand and a rule) :

```
rule = {Im[x_]^2 + Re[x_]^2 -> Abs[x]^2, f_ Re[x_] Re[y_] + f_ Im[x_] Im[y_] -> f Re[Conjugate[x] y]};

Expand[ComplexExpand[Abs[Subscript[z, 1] + Subscript[z, 2]]^2, {Subscript[z, 1],Subscript[z, 2]}, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]] //. rule

Abs[Subscript[z, 1]]^2 + Abs[Subscript[z, 2]]^2 + Re[Conjugate[Subscript[z, 1]] Subscript[z, 2]]

Expand[ComplexExpand[Abs[Subscript[z, 1] + Subscript[z, 2] + Subscript[z, 3]]^2, {Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2], Subscript[z, 3]}, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]] //. rule

Abs[Subscript[z, 1]]^2 + Abs[Subscript[z, 2]]^2 + Abs[Subscript[z, 3]]^2 + Re[Conjugate[Subscript[z, 1]] Subscript[z, 2]] + Re[Conjugate[Subscript[z, 1]] Subscript[z, 3]] + Re[Conjugate[Subscript[z, 2]] Subscript[z, 3]]
```

Comment: Your rule does a mathematically incorrect replacement.  off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @Szabolcs You're right, thanks, edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.htm) and [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.`):

```
res = Expand@ComplexExpand[ Abs[w + z]^2, {w, z}, 
               TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
(*
==> Im[w]^2 + 2 Im[w] Im[z] + Im[z]^2 + Re[w]^2 + 2 Re[w] Re[z] + Re[z]^2
*)

res //. {Im[a_]^2 + Re[a_]^2 :> Abs[a]^2, 
         c_ Im[a_] Im[b_] + c_ Re[a_] Re[b_] :> c Re[Conjugate[a] b] }
(*
==> Abs[w]^2 + Abs[z]^2 + 2 Re[z Conjugate[w]]
*)
```

or, mathematically

$$
\newcommand{asq}[1]{\left|#1\right|^2} \asq{w} + \asq{z} + 2\, \Re(z \bar{w})
$$

This also works with more than 2 variables:

```
(Expand@ComplexExpand[Abs[z + w + x]^2, {z, w, x},
         TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]) //.  
   {Im[a_]^2 + Re[a_]^2 :> Abs[a]^2, 
    c_ Im[a_] Im[b_] + c_ Re[a_] Re[b_] :> c Re[Conjugate[a] b] }
(*
==> Abs[w]^2 + Abs[x]^2 + Abs[z]^2 + 2 Re[x Conjugate[w]] 
     + 2 Re[z Conjugate[w]] + 2 Re[z Conjugate[x]]
*)
```

In mathematical notation:

$$
\asq{w}+\asq{x}+\asq{z}+2\, \Re(x \bar{w})+2\, \Re(z \bar{w})+2\, \Re(z \bar{x}).
$$

Note, `ReplaceRepeated` performs a structural transformation, not a mathematical one, so it is inherently dangerous if you're not careful.

Comment: @szabolcs I changed the conjugate to the overbar style, per the OP. Also, `\newcommand` works, so I used it; check out the edit.

Comment: Wow, MathJax is really good!  The lazy person I am, I just copied the TraditionalForm from Mathematica.  I too like overbar better for conjugate.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I prefer the asterisk form, myself, but to be consistent ...

Comment: Thanks! I have accepted the other answer as they are basically the same as far as I understand and because b.gatessucks was earlier.